# Install MySql in a second PC for JS practicing

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am new to JS and i would like to start playing around with JS and databases.
First of all i think that the first step i should take is to install MySql (correct me if i am wrong).I have a second PC (which i am not using it) with the following system configuration (Intel Core Duo,2.4 Ghz,4 GB Ram), so i am thinking to install MySql there (as a little server).

the next step is to create a form in my HTML page which is going to communicate with my Database.

So my questions are the following:
1) Can i install MySql on the PC i mentioned before considering its configuration? If yes, what are the steps of doing that? (where can i download it and what is the best configuration for the Software to have?)
2) What is the simplest code i must use in order to succeed a connection?

Thank you..

Comment: This would be on-topic on https://superuser.com/ but not here

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may need to learn some more about web development before trying to interact with databases, firstly, it would make it a fair bit easier to install your database on the same machine as it removes a lot of complexity.

You can technically create a form and insert the data using javascript via many hacky methods, but should you do this?... absolutely not, this is not how the web is supposed to work. It would be easily hackable and very unsecure

I would first suggest working on HTML, CSS and JS skills, then learn what an api is and how to consume one, you would be best learning a front end framework like react.js, and pracice building frontend apps using public api's. and then as it seems like you have some understanding of JS, i would recomend learning NodeJS to be able to handle your data, then you can build a simple CRUD app.

Good luck

Comment: Hi Thomas,
thank you for your answer.
As i said, i am new into this so i am sure i;ll have to learn many things.
ok, so you are telling me the best way to interact with a database is with APIs and frameworks in gerenal, right?